# ZF2 Seperate HTML from Recursive PHP function(s)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, zend-framework2

I'm trying to seperate the HTML elements from the PHP code within Zend Framework 2, but I have no clue on how to solve this problem/seperate. Im currently echo'ing those HTML elements, which does the job. But there must be a way to seperate the HTML from PHP, instead of echo'ing the HTML elements.

At the moment I made a viewhelper which helps me to let me generate this treeMap for other modules aswell, since those will also use this feature, aslong as this helper is given with a treeMap. The categoryTreeMap contains a treemap of category (Doctrine 2 ORM) objects.

This is what I've got so far:

```
namespace Application\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class CategoryTreeMapHelper extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function __invoke($categoryTreeMap)
    {
        echo "<ol class=\"sortable\">";
        foreach ($categoryTreeMap as $category) {
            $this->showCategories($category);
        }
        echo "</ol>";
    }

    public function showCategories($category)
    {
        echo "<li><div>" . $category->name . "</div>";
        if (isset($category->childs)) {
            echo "<ol>";
            foreach ($category->childs as $child_category) {
                $this->showCategories($child_category);
            }
            echo "</ol>";
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this, by seperating the HTML from the PHP echo's.

Comment: Is your helper doing anything else other than accepting a single parameter of content and looping over it? If not, this would probably be better solved with partial templates

Comment: I would just build a string and return it for echoing. Generally I dont like to echo from helpers/functions.

Comment: This viewhelper is not doing anything else except printing a list of the tree map with the object names, received by the parameter. The problem is I don't really know how to work with partials, can you give them a parameter for reading the treemap? @Crisp

Comment: Then see my answer below

Comment: @Crisp I would argue that what the OP is doing is pretty much rendering some kind of natigational or sitemap structure. A ViewHelper solves that purpose really well. As far as separation of HTML/PHP goes: why? With a flat structure like this (a simple list) html and PHP can go together. A cleaner approach though would be to do this like the Form View Helpers for example (see `Zend\View\Helper\Element\Select`).

Comment: @Sam, I don't disagree with your premise, I'm just providing an alternative approach that addresses what the OP asked. That said, it's arguably easier to over-ride a template than it is to swap out or otherwise edit a helpers code when a change is needed to cater to some specific display of the underlying list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your helper solely consist of those two methods, you can replicate the functionality in templates by making use of the partial helper

Create a partial for your treemap container

```
// view/partial-treemap.phtml
<ol class="sortable">
    <?php foreach ($this->categoryTreeMap as $category) :
        echo $this->partial('partial-category', array('category' => $category));
     endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

Create a partial for the recursive part (which calls itself recursively for children)

```
// view/partial-category.phtml
<li>
    <div><?php echo $category->name; ?></div>
    <?php if (isset($category->childs)) : ?>
    <ol>
        <?php foreach ($category->childs as $child_category) :
            echo $this->partial('partial-category', array('category' => $child_category));
        endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```

Then in your controller action view you only need one line

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partial-treemap', array('categoryTreeMap' => $categoryTreeMap)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, helped me alot, works just wonderful! =)

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Still have one question; it's looping through all the objects and loading the childs. But how to avoid that it's loading the childs again as root category?

Comment: Figured out: `<?php if(!$category->getParent()): ?>` in the treemap.